# MySQL Order by math

Tags: php, mysql, math, codeigniter

I want to order a result by **fieldx * fieldy**, for example:

Row 1:
fieldx = 10
fieldy = 10
Total: 100

Row 2: 
fieldx = 11
fieldy = 5
Total: 55

Row 1 has to appear first. Couldn't find anything about it. It's for a codeIgniter project, so if there is a solution with that I'm very happy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's okay to do math in the order by clause:

```
 select *
 from YourTable
 order by fieldx * fieldy
```

Comment: Lol, that's easy. Thanks for your time!